# Angular not updating $scope Variable after manual change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

I have a problem with angularjs script.

I have a website for my personal network. 
So I can set bulbs eg. with that site.

I have open the Page an Computer and mobile for example.

So if I set the bulb on mobile phone, light goes off. I could see it on mobile phone and pc with angularjs.

If I set the bulb on, on PC, light goes on, but I only see the result on PC.

On Mobilephone nothing happens. First I have to reset the switch to first value, I can see all changes.

I did not know the Problem for this issue.

After getting new bulb state, I set $rootScope.$apply();

I have to set the state with this code snippet:

```
$rootScope[ 'ng'+receive.data.kLeseAdresse ] = receive.data.cStatus;
$rootScope.$apply();
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Simply i am not clear.. What you mean by `bulb`? have you found any new js library like a `bulb .js`?

Comment: With Bulb, I mean the light bulb in my home rooms :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I have to write more about my script.

To change a scope by pressing a button is no problem, but then if a change is coming by websocket Server, nothing happens. First, I have to set the scope back to first value, websocket could change the variable.